# Javascript Calculation script to calculate form input value's then save as hidden input for page2.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

So ive been spending the last week trying to figure out what im doing wrong.. i have tried to use several other scripts posted to other stack overflow users but can not seem to get anything to do what i need it to do, im still learning html, php and java script so everything is taking me a little while, so any help, advice or input is greatly appreciated.

So in my form i have several input fields that are selection fields, here is some for example:

```
                          </div>
                            <div class="form-field">
                              <label class="frm">*Approx Property Value</label>
                              <select name="fldAPV" title="Approx_Property_Value" id="fldAPV" class="form-action select-details">
                              <option value="100" selected="selected">Select value</option>
                              <option value="100">£0 - £100,000</option>
                              <option value="200">£100,001 - £200,000</option>
                              <option value="300">£200,001 - £300,000</option>
                              <option value="400">£300,001 - £400,000</option>
                              <option value="500">£400,001 - £500,000</option>
                              <option value="600">£500,001 - £600,000</option>
                              <option value="700">£600,001 - £700,000</option>
                              <option value="800">£700,001 - £800,000</option>
                              <option value="9000">£800,001 - £900,000</option>
                              <option value="1Million">£900,001 - £1,000,000</option>
                              </select>
                          </div>
                            <div class="form-field">
                              <label class="frm">*Number of Bedrooms</label>
                              <select name="fldNOBEDS2" title="Number_Of_Bedrooms" id="fldNOBEDS2" class="form-action select-details">
                                <option value="Not_Sure" selected="selected">I'm Not Sure</option>
                                <option value="1">1 Bedroom</option>
                                <option value="2">2 Bedrooms</option>
                                <option value="3">3 Bedrooms</option>
                                <option value="4">4 Bedrooms</option>
                                <option value="5">5 Bedrooms</option>
                                <option value="6">6 Bedrooms</option>
                                <option value="7">7 Bedrooms</option>
                                <option value="8+">8 Bedrooms +</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>                              
                            <div class="form-field">
                                <label class="frm">*Reason for Survey</label>   
                              <select name="fldRFS" title="Reason for Survey" id="fldRFS" class="form-action select-details">
     <option value="Not-Sure" selected="selected">Not Sure</option>
      <option value="Selling">Selling</option>
      <option value="Buying">Buying</option>
      <option value="Other-Reason">Other Reason</option>
  </select>
```

Now what i am trying to achieve is to have a javascript that will calculate the input value on each field the user selects his/hers answer.. My initial thoughts was to do it with each value="" having a default price value so for example the reason for survey fields, instead of saying "Not-Sure" or "Buying" they will say "50" or "100" to represent the cost of the service.

Is it possible to have a script that would understand code like this for example:
    Buying

The reason i say this is i am hoping the value's don't make things confusing, if not then i am happy to use the value="50" for example to determine what the overall cost of the service will be. I guess its the client basically putting together their own package.

The most important part of the script is to make the calculation hidden, so when clicking (View Quote) the form will submit the data either by $_GET or $_POST to page2.php where the client can view their quoted price.

I really hope i have not confused everyone! i see people post very small posts and they seem to get it on the head in one, i can not stress enough i am still learning and we all started somewhere :) This is for my own personal website and one hopes some kind experienced member can help me out, anything is much appreciated as i have spent 6 days trying to figure this out, Thanks!

King Regards

Comment: Im Not through you question now but you should always use POST for forms like this

Comment: You can make a script understanding text with a if Condition or a Select Statement. - But what "Quote" do you want to calulate?

Comment: When do you want to do the calculations? Before the script was send or after? You said you want to use JavaScript but I think its better to use Php. (Performance & not every Client has JS enabeled)

Comment: hi guys, its 6am in the morning here in the uk.. my little girl has just woken up sick, i will post as soon as i possibly can, really appreciate you taking the time to help, Basically when the user is filling out the form, he or she selects the options from the pop down menu while scrolling through the bottom of the form. Upon selecting all the required inputs, user selects (Get my quote now) this takes them to page2.php where hopefully the calculations would have put together the price of there service based on the input value's in the form.. if you get what i mean? sorry got little girl here

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you make a example of your caluclation: That should be the result if the user chooses Value: 600000 Bedrooms: 5 Reason: Buying

Comment: Hi J_S_Stack, just to let you know, i have edited the page now and provided you more details i hope :) thank you for taking the time to help me out :)

Comment: What exactly is the calculation you are trying to do? Add all the values from all the options they chosen?

Comment: Hi Slime,  yes that is correct.. Add all values together so upon clicking (Get my Quote) then sent to page2.php all the information follows by $_POST including the amount calculated from all the values chosen by the user. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP on page2.php:

```
<?php 

If(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $Quote = $_POST['fldST'] + $_POST['fldAPV'] //... For all nummeric Fields

    Switch ($_POST['fldPropertyType']){ 
     /* Use the Switch Statement if you want to compare the same variable 
        (or expression) with   many different values, and execute a different piece of code  
        depending on which value it equals to.      */

        case 'Semi': 
           $Quote  = $Quote + 20; //Replace 20 wit you're Value
        case 'Terraced': 
           $Quote  = $Quote + 50;
        //... For all cases
    }

    //Other Code and Page Content
    echo $Quote;
}
else{
  //ERROR Page was accessed without filling the form in.
}

?>
```

I hope this gives you an good Idea how to do it. Not every Client has Javascript enabeld and you don't know about their Maschine Performance. ist the better way to calculate via PHP.

Importend: NEVER echo/print/use POST/GET Variables direktly! Thats a big leck of Security. Always Filter your User Inputs to prevent Cross-Site-Scripting (XSS)
http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html
http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/website-hacking-part-vi-input-validation-filtering-php/
http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/1.html#1.4.3

<---------------------------------------------- Update ----------------------------------->

When using the code above, Dreamweaver is saying that

```
Switch ($_POST['fldPropertyType']){
```

has a syntax error. Would this affect the script running before I add all the values or is it something simple to rectify?

Thanks

Comment: Does Dw give you further Information? Try it with Switch in small Letters it should be right but I havent tested it

Comment: Also just try it with a short `break;` at the end of every case.

Comment: `If(isset($_POST['submit'])){` and give your submit button the Attribute `name="submit"`

Comment: There is missing a`;` in the Line before

Comment: Please sort out you current code and make a new Question for that. Maybe link this one to it.

Comment: Will make a new question now, keep you eye out lol and then i will be able to Top answer you again as just been watching some videos on youtube, so have a good idea but with your php skills im sure you will do it within 2 seconds!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977028/php-script-to-calculate-form-values-with-default-values-maybe-using-if-and-else            Sorry for the long question, tried to explain better than i did here!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<form>

    <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2" selected>2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

    <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3" selected>3</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit">continue</button>

</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var total = 0;

    $('select').each(function(){

        total += Number($(this).val());

    });

    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: 'page2.php',
        data: { total: total },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){ 

            console.log(result);

        }

    });

});
```

**PHP:**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo JSON_encode($_POST['total']);
```

Comment: PHP seems like overkill for what you're trying to do and I like to do as much of the processing on the client because javascript is widely supported and by doing things off the server it allows you the freedom to scale if you had to.

Comment: i to get an error message with this script until i remote one of the closing tags "    }); "  if i remove one line of them will it affect the script? i am still learning the basics of php and javascript but trying my best, Would function would i use on page2.php to call the total function? would you run echo $_POST['total'] or would i need to run a code snippet of script to implement the total amount in a certain area on the page? Thanks for your time, i understand you will be busy.

Comment: hi slime, i have used the following code to display the total:                    <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>  however it fails to display, tried this on both page2.php that the form posts to and also on the page hosting the above script and form, both fail to show the total.. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @Jrad51 See my edit for full code. I'm using jQuery btw. If you want to show the user, the variable is already in the script, so something like `$('#total').html(total);`

Comment: oh right, will give it a shot now :) i just posted a script i found above too, hopefully we will get your one going as im getting stressed now haha.. takes a lot of stressful hours to learn that's for sure :)

Comment: Hi slime, either i have turned useless or i have tried to take on too much! i had my other site working fine and i seem to cracked it every time.. This site has proved far more difficult!! I appreciate your time i really do, I have edited your post above to show you have i have used the code on a trial run, and still can not get it working, doing 20 hours a day in front of pc has drained my brain big time so i do apologize for being rather useless this evening!