# PHP Script to Calculate Form Values with default values maybe using if and else statements on submit. to page2.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

update for j_s_stack i have added most of the code here for you to see the calculations the script makes, as you know from the comment tab i have made a few changes to the php script and also to the forum script, Changing id's accordingly,

```
            <div class="action-form-field">
              <label class="frm">*Property Type</label>
              <select name="fldPropertyType" id="fldPropertyType" title="Property_Type" class="details-form-action select-details">
                <option value="5" selected>Terraced</option>
                <option value="10">Semi-Detached</option>
                <option value="10">Detached</option>
                <option value="10">Bungalow</option>
                <option value="5">Flat/Apartment</option>
                <option value="10">Other</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="action-form-field">
              <label class="frm">*Approx Property Value</label>
              <select name="fldAPV" title="Approx_Property_Value" id="fldAPV" class="details-form-action select-details">
              <option value="100" selected="selected">Select value</option>
              <option value="100">£0 - £100,000</option>
              <option value="200">£100,001 - £200,000</option>
              <option value="300">£200,001 - £300,000</option>
              <option value="400">£300,001 - £400,000</option>
              <option value="500">£400,001 - £500,000</option>
              <option value="600">£500,001 - £600,000</option>
              <option value="700">£600,001 - £700,000</option>
              <option value="800">£700,001 - £800,000</option>
              <option value="900">£800,001 - £900,000</option>
              <option value="1000">£900,001 - £1,000,000</option>
              <option value="1150">£1,000,001 - £2,000,000</option>
              <option value="1350">£2,000,001 - £5,000,000</option>
              <option value="1500">£5,000,001 and above</option>
              </select>
          </div>
            <div class="action-form-field">
              <label class="frm">*Number of Bedrooms</label>
              <select name="fldNOBEDS" title="Number_Of_Bedrooms" id="fldNOBEDS" class="details-form-action select-details">
                <option value="15" selected="selected">I'm Not Sure</option>
                <option value="5">1 Bedroom</option>
                <option value="10">2 Bedrooms</option>
                <option value="15">3 Bedrooms</option>
                <option value="20">4 Bedrooms</option>
                <option value="25">5 Bedrooms</option>
                <option value="30">6 Bedrooms</option>
                <option value="35">7 Bedrooms</option>
                <option value="50">8 Bedrooms +</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          <div class="action-form-field">
              <label class="frm">*Select Survey Required</label>
              <select name="fldST" title="Survey_Type" id="fldST" class="details-form-action select-details">
                <option value="not-sure" selected="selected">I'm Not Sure</option>
                <option value="15">RICS Condition Survey</option>
                <option value="25">RICS Homebuyer Survey</option>
                <option value="50">RICS Building Survey</option>
              </select>
            </div>
        </div>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="GET YOUR INSTANT QUOTE" class="cash-btn">
```

**THE PHP SCRIPT**

```
 <?php 

    function calculate(){
        $calculate = $_POST['fldNOBEDS'] + $_POST['fldAPV'] + $_POST['fldPropertyType']; //... 
        return $calculate;
    }

    If(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if($_POST['fldST'] == 'not-sure'){
           $quote =  calculate() + 45;
           echo 'condition Quote: '.$quote;
           $quote =  calculate() + 125;
           echo 'homebuyer Quote: '.$quote;
           $quote =  calculate() + 150;
           echo 'building Quote: '.$quote;
           $quote =  calculate() + 50;
           echo 'valuation Quote: '.$quote;
        }
       else{
           $quote = calculate() + $_POST['fldST'];
           echo 'Your Quote: '.$quote;
       }               
    }
    else{
      //ERROR Page was accessed without filling the form in.
    }
    ?>
```

Example When Selecting Values of what they should show:

```
  <option value="5" selected>Terraced</option>
  <option value="100">£0 - £100,000</option>
  <option value="5">1 Bedroom</option>
  <option value="15">RICS Condition Survey</option>
```

Total should be:  Your Quote: 125  (Correct)

When i select "not-sure" as my survey type the answer is:

```
condition Quote: 65
homebuyer Quote: 235
building Quote: 260
valuation Quote: 160
```

<<<<------------------  UPDATE FOR FINAL SECTION ----------------->>>>>>

```
        <!-- action block1 -->
        </form>
        <form name="form2" id="form2" method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="Name" id="Name" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Email" id="Email" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Phone" id="Phone" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Postcode" id="Postcode" value="" />
        <!-- action block2 -->
        <div class="inner_actionblock2">
            <div class="inner_actionblock_top">
                <p class="cash_head">Assisted Sale</p>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_actionblock_mid">
                <div class="actiobox_shade-new"></div>
                <div class="inr_action_list">
                    <ul>
                        <li>.... Text about Surveys......</li>
                        <li>.... Text about Surveys......</li>
                        <li>.... Text about Surveys......</li>
                        <li>.... Text about Surveys......</li>
                </div>
                <div class="ur_offer">Your Condition Survey Quote is:</div>
                <div class="box_center">
                    <div class="action_txt_fld">
                        <span><img src="sign2.png" alt="" /></span>
                        <div class="action_txt_fldbox">
                            <input type="text" name="pricetxt" class="price_txt" readonly value="<?php echo $quote?>"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="last_boxtext">Please Confirm Contact Number:</p>
                    <p class="inputbox"><input type="text" name="pnumber" id="pnumber" value="" class="tbox"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="action_cash1"><input type="submit" id="button3" class="action_cash1_submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_block"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- block2 -->
        </form>
```

I have added the code of each box where the survey report quoted price is listed, As you can see in the value i have the "" from previously, So i guess i can try using a h1 - h5 tag and see what suits best?

Thanks.

Comment: Could u tell your need in a nutshell mate.I really can't understand your need.

Comment: @Outlooker its a bit complicated: This is the first Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957178/javascript-calculation-script-to-calculate-form-input-values-then-save-as-hidde/27970727#27970727 To Sort the things out I asked Jrad51 to make a new Question

Comment: I cann't see the sens of your addtwo function! That Function just does a simple Addition of two Variables.

Comment: Sorry out looker i am still trying to lean, Sometimes saying too much is confusing i guess rather than keeping it simple, the problem is i do not yet know what to ask for to keep it simple as still learning the codes and phrases :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put all the caluclation stuff in a function. And then Make another IF Condition to see what the user has choosen:

```
<?php 

    function calulate(){
        $calc = $_POST['fldAgeOfProp'] + $_POST['fldAPV']; //... 
        Switch ($_POST['fldPropertyType']){                 
                    case 'Semi': 
                       $calc  = $calc + 60;
                    case 'Terraced': 
                       $calc  = $calc + 40;
                    //... For all cases
        }
        return $calc;
    }

    If(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if($_POST['fldST'] == 'not-sure'){
           $quote =  calculate();
           $quote1 =  $quote + 45;
           echo 'condition Quote: '.$quote1;
           $quote2 =  $quote + 125;
           echo 'homebuyer Quote: '.$quote2;
           $quote3 =  $quote + 150;
           echo 'building Quote: '.$quote3;
           $quote4 = $quote + 50;
           echo 'valuation Quote: '.$quote4;
        }
       else{
           $quote =  calculate() + $_POST['fldST'];
           echo 'Your Quote: '.$quote;
       }               
    }
    else{
      //ERROR Page was accessed without filling the form in.
    }
    ?>
```

I haven't tested it again so their might be some mistakes in it.

Comment: Take youre time to have a look on the code and to understand what I did. By the way: My Name `is j_s_stack` with a t

Comment: My mistake it should be `calculate()`

Comment: Don't need to. I do this here, becouse I needed a lot of help in the beginning too and now I just want to give back as much as I can...

Comment: That has no Impact on it since the caluclation is in a function now. The Proplem was a spelling Mistake. The variable is called `$quote` but in the `echo` I wrote `$Quote`.

Comment: You Need to Change the added Values For the Condition Quote I added 45

Comment: oh right yes, sorry its late here lol lack of sleep but really wanted to get finished for tomorrow witch is now today! :)  The only thing left now to complete the form is how can i echo the total of each price when the user selects "not-sure" as i need to display each price in a css box, i have 4 boxes.. 1 for each service, so they can view the price below Information about that specific survey, as right now the echo is throwing them out like:  condition Quote: 155homebuyer Quote: 235building Quote: 260valuation Quote: 160 so if i can have a snippet for each one i could move then into the css

Comment: whats your HTML Struktur?

Comment: replace each echo with something like this:  `echo '<div><h3>homebuyer Quote:</h3><p> '.$quote.'</p></div>;` With the `.` you conntect Strings. So you just Need the HTML Code aroeund the echo of the Quote Variable

Comment: Added the last and final update part to give you an idea what the layout is like where each Quoted price is displayed to the customer.

Comment: due to all the survey report quotes prices being called  that same as 'condition Quote: '.$quote; when i use $quote tag it trys to call both the fldNOBEDS + fldAPV + fldPropertyType calculate and also the fldST calculate, is there a php command to mirror the fldST $quote and call this $quote2 for condition report, $quote3 for homebuyer and $quote4 for Building survey for example? i can then insert each snippet into 4 different boxes in order to provide all 4 prices should the user select "not-sure"  its causing problems i know but its very common for clients to not know what survey they need

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$quote1' (T_VARIABLE) in /action2/index.php on line 12        copied that section and syntax error in dreamweaver + firefox error states above

Comment: Really do need to go to bed now! its 8:08am and been getting 4 hours sleep a day trying to do this website :( I really appreciate your help j_s_stack its been a pleasure having you help out, unfortunately i don't have the energy to stay awake now though, If you could think of some possible options i will resume as soon as i open my eyes later today! Was hoping to get this completed by tonight and 12 hours from now is 8pm so looks like i wont be going to bed for to long haha!  Thanks again and will catch up tomorrow my brain is now dead!

Comment: `unexpected`always means that there is a ; or ),} ... missing. In this case a `;` after the Calculate.